# Hugo Server not rebuilding on file changes

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, hugo

I have a project which is having a folder size of around 1.6 GB. When I try to build the project by running (on ubuntu server with 8GB memory),

hugo server --bind=0.0.0.0

Watching for changes in /root/hugo/{content,layouts,static}
Watching for config changes in /root/hugo/config.toml
Serving pages from memory
Running in Fast Render Mode. For full rebuilds on change: hugo server --disableFastRender
Web Server is available at http://localhost:1313/ (bind address 0.0.0.0)
Press Ctrl+C to stop

It will take around 20 minutes and 7 GB of ram to start and after that If I change a file (ex: index.md in content folder), It is not rebuilding..

On the same server, If I tried building a sample project and changes the file, It show..

Change detected, rebuilding site ..

What may be the reason? Is it because of the huge memory consumption?

Thanks /-

Answer (score 0):

The memory consumption sounds like the probable cause. For each .md file, Hugo will generate several .html files. There are the content pages themselves, the tag and category pages, and the navigation-type pages that redirect to the content pages from equivalent URLs. The generated HTML files are also generally bigger than the input .md files.

On top of that, you have the memory which is being used by Hugo for the conversion, and also the memory used by the rest of your OS and your other apps. I wouldn't be at all surprised if all of that took you over 8GB of memory usage, and once you go over that, your OS will start swapping memory out to the hard disk, which will slow your computer down considerably.

How much space does your site take up on disk when you render it normally with `hugo` instead of `hugo server`? That will give you an idea of how much memory you would be taking up.